# How do I prevent clicking in-page links from pushing up the suite bar in Firefox in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, hyperlink, suitebar

In Firefox, when I click a link in a page that points to an anchor in the same page, it takes me to the appropriate section of the page, but then it also pushes half of the top/suite bar offscreen. Please see below:

[image: Half-obscured top/suite bar in Firefox after clicking an in-page link]

This also occurs if I manually enter the anchor in the address bar. I have tested this with all add-ons and extensions disabled and still I get this behavior. How can I click a link and still see the entire top/suite bar?

Comment: Do you use any custom css or javascript on the site?

Comment: @DanielZiga No.